# Historical & current use of MS_INVALIDATE

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have been trying to understand the correct use of this flag but there are conflicting information around the internet.

My understanding is that this flag currently a no-op in the linux kernel.
https://github.com/tinganho/linux-kernel/blob/master/mm/msync.c

Any historical reasons( design choices ) due to which this flag was added ?

Answer (score 1):

In the code from [`msync.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/msync.c) one can see:

```
    if ((flags & MS_INVALIDATE) &&
            (vma->vm_flags & VM_LOCKED)) {
        error = -EBUSY;
        goto out_unlock;
    }
```

Basically here, we know that `MS_INVALIDATE` is being evaluated and if the current mapping pointed by `vma` is locked, the `msync()` call will fail with `EBUSY`.

This makes sense according to (from *part of release 3.74 of the Linux man-pages project, `msync(2)`*):

> `MS_INVALIDATE` asks to invalidate other mappings of the same file (so
>   that they can be updated with the fresh values just written).

Because if any file map linked to `vma` list is locked, it cannot be invalidated, so the call will fail when otherwise (being otherwise not setting the `MS_INVALIDATE` flag) it will not.

So, now answering your question, it cannot be considered a no-op, since it affects the behaviour of `msync()` when set.